# IQR Outlier detection

Tags: statistics

For outlier detection i used the IQR rule. My question is, is this kind of outlier detection only useful then applied to normal distributed data?

[My distribution looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QyOl.png)

Comment: Also appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your distribution looks like a normal one but with negative values taken in absolute value (folded normal). You should be able to tell, from the way the data is generated. If the right tail is sifficiently close to normal, you can use the quartile rule on the right.

Comment: The $1.5\times\text{IQR}$ rule can be applied to any distribution. Because you're using percentiles to determine outliers, and percentiles are robust to said outliers, the $1.5\times\text{IQR}$ works on any distribution.

Answer (score -1):

The most commonly-used IQR outlier-detection rule, designates as an 'outlier' any observation
above Q3 + 1.5(IQR) or below Q1 - 1.5(IQR), where Q1 is the lower quartile, Q3 is the upper quartile and IQR = Q3 - Q1. The use of this rule is not restricted to normal data.

However, it is important to realize that some distributions are inherently more likely to show outliers than others. On average, a sample of size $n = 100$ from a normal
distribution will typically show about one outlier, as illustrated by the following simulation
in R statistical software, counting outliers in 100,000 such samples.

```
nr.out = replicate( 10^5, length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(100))$out) )
mean(nr.out)
$$ 0.92325
```

An analogous simulation for samples of size 100 from an exponential distribution
shows an average of about 4.85 outliers per sample. This is because exponential
distributions have a heavy right tail. It would be unusual for an exponential
sample of size 100, *not* to show at least one outlier.

```
nr.out = replicate(10^5, length(boxplot.stats(rexp(100))$out ))
mean(nr.out)
## 4.8561
mean(nr.out == 0)
## 0.00952
```

By contrast, uniform distributions 'have no tails' and samples of size 100
from a uniform distribution almost never show any outliers.

Of course, in real data some outliers may occur because of an unusual departure from population values. For example, data entry error, equipment failure, solar flair, and so on. In certain kinds of experiments, it is *only* the outliers that
are of interest. It was outlier events in the collider at CERN that confirmed the
existence of Higgs bosons. Many earthquakes are detected worldwide
every day; it is only the extreme outliers that cause damage and so are of interest to the general public.

So, you can use the IQR method of identifying 'outliers' in trying to understand data from almost any population as long
as you understand how to interpret what it means to be an outlier in your particular context.